# Rails Person model with different roles as subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, composition, subclassing, user-roles

I’m working with Ruby on Rails, but this question applies to application/database model design in general. I want to model many types of people such as User (someone who can log in), Employee, and Customer. Each of these has common attributes like name and email that should be part of a Person superclass. Each type also has other more specific attributes. A Person can be one or more of these roles (someone can be both an employee and a customer).

In code, the appropriate structure seems like a superclass/subclass relationship, but from a database normalization perspective, there should be a Customer table that references the Person table for its common attributes.

I need to decide how to combine these two approaches.

For example, I want to be able to create a Customer by `Customer.create(name: “Johnny Appleseed”, favorite_product: widget)` and query `Employee.where(email: “someone@company.com”)`, and avoid duplicating Person fields on every role model. That way I can change the way I model a Person without needing to update all the other tables with the same changes.

Comment: Can User be same person as Customer and Employee? I think you are really trying to have one table, with a way to say which person is employee, customer or both.

Comment: Are you thinking `Role` < `Person` when you say "the appropriate structure seems like a superclass/subclass relationship"?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use Single Table Inheritance.
You can start from this tutorial https://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/